# Null exception on gettting EngineByName?

Tags: java, groovy

I am using diff ways getEngineByName("groovy") and I am failing in all of them, as I am new to groovy, I have no idea what I am missing

```
        ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("groovy");



//      ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
//      ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("groovy");
```

in both lines the `engine = null` 
please help!

[image: how libraries look]

Comment: Probably your're missing the groovy jar file in your classpath? That's not shipped with the JRE I think

Comment: How can I check if that is there?
or how can I add it there, can you help me, please @Jan

Comment: well how do you run this code? From an IDE like eclispe? Then check project classpath for groovy dependency

Comment: Have a look I just upload a photo, yeah I am using Eclipse, and I think i have added the groovy dependencies @jan

Comment: you might be missing groovy-jsr223

Answer (score 2):

Best guess at this point: As you're relying on JSR-223 scripting to find Groovy Engine (which is not encouraged by Groovy, but possible), you should add groovy-jsr223 lib to your classpath as well

Maven: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-jsr223

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
    <artifactId>groovy-jsr223</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

or in gradle:

```
compile group: 'org.codehaus.groovy', name: 'groovy-jsr223', version: '3.0.4'
```

Comment: // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-jsr223
compile group: 'org.codehaus.groovy', name: 'groovy-jsr223', version: '3.0.4'
is like this but if I don't change to classpath group it doesn't build, how can I check if is imported correctly as I tried much time and still doesn't work

Comment: if I use 'compile' it doesn't get build @jan

Comment: buildscript {
 dependencies {
  classpath group: "com.liferay", name: "com.liferay.gradle.plugins.workspace", version: "2.2.3"
  classpath group: "net.saliman", name: "gradle-properties-plugin", version: "1.4.6"

 }

 repositories {
  maven {
   url "https://repository-cdn.liferay.com/nexus/content/groups/public"
  }
 }
}

apply plugin: "net.saliman.properties"

apply plugin: "com.liferay.workspace"

Comment: you could download from the maven repo and add to project manually - just to make sure that solves the problem. I'm not too deep in gradle, so I'd have to pass on that one :-)

Comment: thank you for your efforts and time @jan, I will figure out how to do it

Comment: If you get it to work feel free to upvote / accept an answer to your question :-)